# GARCH with Student errors produces an error message in R (but GARCH with normal errors runs fine)

Tags: r, garch, error-message

I am estimating the volatility of exchange rate returns using GARCH(1,1) with the following code:

```
m1 = garchFit(~1+garch(1,1), data = EUR_SEK, trace = F)
```

As soon as I change the distribution from normal to $t$ by running the code

```
m2=garchFit(~1+garch(1,1), data = EUR_SEK, trace = F, cond.dist = "std")
```

R produces an error:

```
Error in solve.default(fit$hessian) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.46196e-16
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: It is unlikely anyone is going to be able to help you without further details of your dataset. You may want to consider whether a list like R-help would have more readers who can help you with details of R coding.

Comment: Have you tried a different algorithm using the argument `algorithm` in function [`garchfit`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/fGarch/docs/garchFit)? Have you tried supplying a different set of initial values to the optimization routine? Do you get the same error if you remove the first or the last observation of your data?